# Reading/Printing 'Logo' Image in J2ME

Tags: java-me

I'm developing an application in J2ME using NetBeans, here I'm working on a task, printing the receipts with image logo on the top of the receipt.
To print so we are using Bluetooth handheld printers.
With the help of Bluetooth, I'm connecting to the printer and I'm able to print the text in the desired format.

In case of printing the logo image, I'm unable to read it.

Can you please guide me how to read the image file and sent to the printer in byte array and character array.